# RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl

I tried to put `verify_ssl=>false` to the request, but it doesn't work.

Below is my code:

```
def login_request (username, password)
  request_body_map = {:userName => username, :password => password}
  request_header = {:content_type => 'application/json', :accept => 'application/json'} 
  begin
    res = RestClient.post endpoint, request_body_map.to_json, {:header => request_header, :verify_ssl => false} 
    response_data = JSON.parse(res.body) 
  rescue Exception => e raise e
  end
end
```

Comment: maybe duplicate question, please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255071/restclient-get-returning-certificate-verify-failed

Answer (score 3):

please use `RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: url, headers: headers, verify_ssl: false)`

`verify_ssl` is not accepted in RestCient.method

Comment: @DannyG author of the question wanted to use `verify_ssl`, and this is the syntax to use, if the insecure is about turning off the ssl verification, otherwise, I would like to know how is it insecure?

Comment: If you are not verifying the SSL very, it’s possible it’s a fraud.

Comment: @DannyG originally question is having a wrong syntax...weather or not enabling ssl, my answer is the right syntax

Comment: Not debating that, just calling out the security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def login_request (username, password)
  request = {'userName': username, 'password': password}.to_json
  url = "#{$url_host}#{$login_api}"
  begin
    res = RestClient.post(
        url,
        request,
        :content_type => :json, :accept => :json,
        :verify_ssl => false)
    response_data = JSON.parse(res.body) 
    $user_token = response_data['token'] 
    $userId = response_data['user']['userId'] 
    p response_data['user']['email'] 
  rescue Exception => e
  end
end
```

You can put the authentication details with `:varify_ssl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Still not working...I've researched this issue for a month but it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

We're facing the same exact error (B: certificate verify failed) and it's driving me nuts. This started showing up for our developers around the 10th of Oct, 2015.

In authorize.net developer forums there are **many threads** with the same issue, two of which are recent ([first thread](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Response-returning-empty/td-p/52524/highlight/true/page/6)) ([second thread](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/SSL-Error/m-p/52522/highlight/true#M27756)) and both went dead with no resolution, these two threads started around the same time we started facing this issue, so my guess is that it has to do with authorize.net bad/new certificate with missing certificate chain.

This exact issue appeared before around 2012 and 2014 (check their developer forum), Authorize.net admitted it was a bad change they made to their certificates and then later fixed the issue, but this time it appears to be an ongoing since mid October.

PS: I tried installing every root/chain certificate on our server but this issue persists.

Comment: The issue is gone when I change the way to call the request, like this: 

res = RestClient::Request.execute(:url => endpoint,
                                        :method => :post,
                                        :headers => request_header,
                                        :payload => request_body_map.to_json,
                                        :verify_ssl => false)
      response_data = JSON.parse(res.body)

Hope this help! ^^

Comment: Thanks @NguyenThu, for me it turned out the developers were using faulty authorize.net configurations.

Comment: I was able to resolve this as a result of swapping out the certificate chain on the server.