# RestClient.get returning certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, ssl, rest-client

I am trying hit an internal testing API server using RestClient and Ruby v. 2.2.1.

This is essentially the code:

```
url = "https://10.10.0.10/thing/i/want/to/get"
header = {
      :content_type => "application/json",
      :"x-auth-token" => "testingtoken"
  }
response = RestClient.get url, header
```

This is the failure message I get:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified)
```

If I'm reading this right, it looks like Ruby couldn't accept the SSL security certificate.  This call works in the Chrome app Postman, but in order for it to work, I have to hit the URL in Chrome itself and accept that the connection is not secure (but proceed anyway), and THEN it will work in postman.

Is there a way to ignore the certificate failures and proceed anyway in Ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL\_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `#execute(&block)` with `verify_ssl` set to `false`.

> `:verify_ssl` enable ssl verification, possible values are constants
>   from `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_*`, defaults to `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER`

```
url = "https://10.10.0.10/thing/i/want/to/get"
headers = {
  :content_type => "application/json",
  :"x-auth-token" => "testingtoken"
}

RestClient::Request.execute(
  :url => url, 
  :method => :get, 
  :headers => headers,
  :verify_ssl => false
)
```

*see: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/RestClient/Request#execute-instance_method*

---

**RVM**

Additional solution for RVM users from: https://toadle.me/2015/04/16/fixing-failing-ssl-verification-with-rvm.html

> This [discussion on Github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3330) finally gave the solution: Somehow RVM comes
>   with a precompiled version of ruby that is statically linked against
>   an openssl that looks into `/etc/openssl` for it's certificates.
>
> What you wanna do is NOT TO USE any of the precompiled rubies and
>   rather have ruby compiled on your local machine, like so: 
>   `rvm install 2.2.0 --disable-binary`

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first solution is an insecure workaround and defeats the purpose of having an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

`rest-client` verify certificates using the system's CA store on all platforms by default. But is possible set to false the option `:verify_ssl` or specify `:ssl_ca_file` or `:ssl_ca_path` or `:ssl_cert_store` to customize the certificate authorities accepted.

See [documentation](http://You%20can%20specify%20an%20:ssl_ca_file,%20:ssl_ca_path,%20or%20:ssl_cert_store%20to%20customize%20the%20certificate%20authorities%20accepted.)

So you could simply set `:verify_ssl` to false:

```
url = "https://10.10.0.10/thing/i/want/to/get"
header = {
      :content_type => "application/json",
      :"x-auth-token" => "testingtoken"
}
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
  url,
  headers: header,
  verify_ssl: false
)

response = resource.get
```

You could try immediately with a host which use a self-signed certificated provided by https://badssl.com/. Simply copy the snippet below in your irb console.

```
response = RestClient::Resource.new(
 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/',
  :verify_ssl =>  false
).get
```

Comment: Your documentation link is broken