# undefined local variable or method `api' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Hi guys i'm new on RoR and have question, 
i'm getting this error on my Terminal when i'm trying to run  ***>  ruby api_controller.rb***

**undefined local variable or method `api' for main:Object (NameError)**

**Here my code:**

```
 require 'rubygems'  
 require 'httparty'

 url = https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/ 
 response = HTTParty.get(url) 
 response.parsed_response


 class Coinmarketcap
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'api.coinmarketcap.com'

   def listings
     self.class.get('/v2/listings/')
   end 
 end


 coinmarketcap = Coinmarketcap.new 
 puts coinmarketcap.listings

 coinmarketcap.listings.each do |post|   
  #puts "Id: #{post['id']        
 end
```

Comment: I think you forgot the quote `"` arround the url definition, should be `url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/"`

Comment: What happend when you run the three lines directly in console? (rails c)

Comment: hi guys, please watch the conversation below with LolWalid. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing quote arround the url

Should be:

```
url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings'
```

I copy/paste your code and it's working with above modification

Comment: i tried it and now i received the error "cannot load such file -- httparty" i researched about it and tried also with: gem install httparty, or manuely i add gem 'httparty', '0.16.2' and bundle install

Comment: @HenrikZakaryan Ok you have a problem with your gems, `httparty` seems to not be installed, tape `gem install httparty`, then `gem list httparty` to check that it has been well installed

Comment: i just found the problem, i had to start the server new :). after start i got this problem: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed.... for sure i researched about it and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629333/restclientsslcertificatenotverified-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv
i added it but receive another problem:  uninitialized constant RestClient (NameError) __

Thank you for helping